# Disk I/O performance issue

Tags: linux, performance, io, disk, raid5

I have a Dell PowerEdge R820 server which is under maintenance by other third party. There are 6 SAS (10K RPM, 6gbps) disks and they are configured as RAID 5 using PERC controller.

Currently I am facing performance issue with the server. Basically it is with the disk. When I tried to write 4GB of data, it is taking 12 minutes to complete. I am using a Linux Server.

Please see the output of dd command:

```
# # time dd if=/dev/zero of=TestFile bs=4096 count=1024000
1024000+0 records in
1024000+0 records out
real    12m 3.56s
user    0m 7.94s
sys 0m 0.00s
```

I have also checked with the other Desktop made server, where RAID 5 is configured with 4 SATA (7.2K RPM) disks. It is taking only 19 seconds to write 4GB of data to the disk.

I can see the clear problem of disk I/O performance issue. But the third party is denying, they are telling that, this is the normal time. But I refuse to agree with them.

Can you please tell me what should be the normal time to write 4GB data to the volume configured with 6SAS (10K RPM) disks?

Comment: The file system matters though. You should also consider using `oflag=direct`  or `oflag=nocache,sync` for a realistic write speed. A faulty drive might also slow down the raid performance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because

I think it should be moved to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does seem like a disk performance issue.

You should get something in between 20 MB/s to 80 MB/s depending on block size I think.
I found this old 10k disk comparison where you can see how different drives are performing http://techreport.com/review/5236/10k-rpm-hard-drive-comparison/7 .

I also found a thread from dell forum where someone is facing same kind of issue:
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/t/19475037

To answer you question: No 5-6 MB/s is not normal.

Comment: JFC. That's ugly engineering. (Sounds as if it uses some high-overhead method to close the RAID5 write hole w/o having any separate non-volatile memory.  I.e. a data journal, requiring synchronous writes).

Answer (score 1):

That's a reasonable test for sequential writes.  General hard disk performance should be in the region of 100MB/s.  You should include a final `sync` in the timings, which could be why your desktop appears to run 2x that speed.

You might see variance around +-30 on different types of drives.  RAID can affect that, but in general it shouldn't cause a significant slowdown, not to sequential writes.  (Maybe if you had used `conv=sync`).

Your server should not be running sequential writes at 5MB/s, that is just wrong.  Note that one cause of slow performance is a failing disk.